# Split a string on sql

Tags: sql, string, split

I have this string on one of the columns on my database table

```
black lines^TECH43223
```

I need to split the string, and this is my code to split the string

```
Select LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Complaint, CHARINDEX('^',Complaint)+1, len(Complaint))) from       Service
```

and the result is

```
TECH43223
```

But what I need is that string "black lines". Can I split the string, and get the first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close!! The `SUBSTRING()` function works as follows:

`SUBSTRING( Value, Start Position, Length)`

Start from the beginning of the string, and trim at the occurrence of the character:

`SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Complaint, 1, CHARINDEX('^',Complaint) ) from Service`

Test it, if the result includes your split character `^` you may need to subtract 1:

`SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Complaint, 1, CHARINDEX('^',Complaint)-1 ) from Service`

Comment: ah you got it, i'll remove mine.

Comment: @set Thanks bro ! you're a genius, haha . i'm already creating my function for this problem, then you came . thank you so much !